# Is it possible to capture the entire Screen including the Taskbar and/or the explorer with the Windows 10 Game Bar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, gaming, screen-capture

The Windows 10 Game Bar allows recording most applications, but it doesn't seem to work for the explorer or the entire screen. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Windows Explorer or Internet Explorer?  What do you exactly mean by the "entire screen"? Cause I have had no trouble recording video of my desktop using the Game DVR application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain words

No, It is not possible to capture the entire Screen including the Taskbar and/or the explorer with the Windows 10 Game Bar.

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> simply won't pop-up any thing on Explorer or on Desktop